# Getting answers from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, compare

I am making an online test script where you can input the answers in the input elements. Once the test is submitted I want the database's answers to be compared with the inputted answers to say whether it is wrong or not, however the script I am using is not working! :S

Here is the problem!
In the database, I have 4 out of 50 ready answers set (not all yet) when I answer both 4 correct or wrong it returns them being incorrect. It lists all the answers, whether they're correct or incorrect in the page but it's not working correctly, no matter what inputs I do, it all the answers up to 49 say incorrect, then for some reason 50 says correct?...

Here is my script:

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dstsbsse","pass","user");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "ERROR - Failed to connect to MySQL Server. Please contact an Administrator at    English In York: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//Set variables to hold output data and total score.

$output="";
$score=0;

//for-next loop.  This means "Set n to value one.  Every time through the loop (between {}) increase n by one.  Do this while n is less than or equal to 50"

for($n=1;$n<=50;$n++)
    {
    $sql="SELECT a$n FROM answer WHERE 1";
    // $sql="SELECT * FROM answer WHERE name='a$n'";  //sql is specific to your table of course - you will need to change this.
    $result = $con->query($sql); // perform the query
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  //load the result into the array $row
    $key="a".$n;                     //concatenate to generate the $_POST keys
    if($row['answer']==$_POST[$key]) //compare the data from the table with the answer
        {
        //answer is correct
        $score++;
        $output.="Answer $n is correct</BR>"; //add responses to the output string
        }
        else
        {
        $output.="Answer $n is incorrect</BR>";
        }
    }
$output.="Total score: $score/50";  //add the score
echo $output;  //echo to screen.
```

Here is an example of one of the questions answer boxes:

```
<input type="text" name="a1" id="a1" required>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Fetching a query like:

```
SELECT a1 FROM answer
```

would return `$row['a1']`, instead of `$row['answer']`

So you should be using the column name, not the table one

Comment: It is still returning as if it was wrong. Could it be the database?